# Outlook 2010: how can I to add a default signature to an open email

Tags: vba, outlook

Not sure why Outlook never put in a signature for emails that were created outside of it. like in Windows Explorer; right clicking on a file and then click Send... there are others too.
I want to add a button to my quick access tool bar to simply pop it in on the email that is showing.
clicking the Smibbon takes 3 or 4 clicks :(

I was able to get the default signature, but can't figure out how to insert it.

```
Public Sub InsertDefaultSignature()

  Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim ObjMail As Outlook.MailItem

  DirSig = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & _
                               "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures"

  FileNameHTMSig = Dir$(DirSig & "\*.htm")

  Set OlApp = Outlook.Application
  Set ObjMail = OlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'need something here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook will add the default signature when you either call MAilItem.Display or call MailItem.GetInspector (you can ignore the default value).

Comment: Ok I changed it to this   ObjMail.Display   which creates a new blank email. I have an email on the screen already without a signature, I am not creating new emails, and I want to add a signature to it. I want one button to insert a signature, instead of clicking the ribbon and the whatever else you have to do.

Comment: Please show your code. Does Outlook insert the signature when you create a new message?